# Monorepo (lerna) - circular dependency

Tags: npm, lerna

is it possible for a monorepo to have two packages which depend on one another?

E.g.

**package_Dashboard**

`import { table } from 'package_Style'`

**package_Style**

`import { style } from 'package_Dashboard'`

During development, all seems to be working more or less fine thanks to aliases/references which replace
`package_Dashboard` with `../package_Dashboard'`.

I have to not include the dependency in one of the package.json files, because otherwise lerna warns me about a circular dependency.
When I'd publish this on npm or similar, this wouldn't work anymore (due to the missing dependency in package.json).

So how does one best solve for a case like this?

Thanks!

Comment: don't know if it is possible to solve for circular dependency but I imagine you can create another package that will eliminate the circularity. for example, moving 'table' to a different package and have both existing packages import from it